# Mapping values in cells/column of GridView ASP/C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a grideview in ASP/C# filled up with data from a SQL data source. Some columns contain an ID (integer) in which each has a different mapping to it. I want to display the mapped value instead of an integer. For example, the first column in the GrideView displays 1, 2, 3, 4 (Exactly as from the DB). But instead, I want to show it to the users as strings based on the mapping:

```
1 = Cash
2 = Money Transfer
3 = Visa
4 = etc
```

How do I do it from C# without involving CASE functionality in my select statement?

Comment: Are the mappings in tables of your database? If so, you could use 'INNER JOIN`s in your query to get the string corresponding to each ID.

Comment: Yes.  For most of the mappings, I do have their description in a different table. How would I do that. I am not so familiar with sql advanced queries. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the mappings are stored in your database, you can use `INNER JOIN` in your query to get the mapped values.

For example, if you have an `Orders` table with the fields `OrderID`, `ClientID`, `Price` and `PaymentTypeID`:

```
OrderID   ClientID  Price   PaymentTypeID
   3          8      40.50       3
   4          2     128.43       1
```

A `Clients` table with the fields `ClientID` and `ClientName`:

```
ClientID  ClientName
   2      Woolworth
   3      Dairy Queen
   6      Dominion Groceries
   8      Miracle Mart
```

And a `PaymentType` table with the fields `PaymentTypeID` and `Description`:

```
PaymentTypeID  Description
     1         Cash
     2         Money transfer
     3         Visa
```

Then the query could look like this:

```
SELECT
    O.*,
    C.ClientName,
    PT.Description AS PaymentDescription
FROM
    Orders O
    INNER JOIN Clients C ON C.ClientID = O.ClientID
    INNER JOIN PaymentType PT ON PT.PaymentTypeID = O.PaymentTypeID
```

In your GridView, you could display some fields from the `Orders` table, but also the fields `ClientName` and `PaymentDescription` returned by the query:

```
ClientName       Price    PaymentDescription
Miracle Mart     40.50         Visa
Woolworth       128.43         Cash
```

The ID's themselves are usually not shown to the user. If you need their values for some processing in code-behind, you can add them to the `DataKeyNames` of the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" DataKeyNames="OrderID,ClientID,PaymentTypeID" ... >
```

and get their values like this:

```
gvOrders.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values["PaymentTypeID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Model property that corresponds to the property that is being retrieved right now?

For example, if this property is called `PaymentOptionID`, there should be a corresponding `String` to hold the `PaymentOptionDescription`. Then when you're returning your recordset from your DB, assign the gridview's column the **string** property instead. Example below:

**Model**

```
public class PaymentOption
{
    public int PaymentOptionID {get; set;}
    public string PaymentOptionDescription {get; set;}
}
```

**DB Select Statement**

```
SELECT
        [fldPaymentOptionID]
        ,[fldPaymentOptionDescription]
        ,[fldMyOtherFields]
FROM    [tblPaymentOptions]
```

**Controller Method**

```
public ViewResult GetPaymentOptionGridViewSource()
{
    PaymentOption myPaymentOptions = new PaymentOption();

    Viewbag.PaymentOptionGridSource = myPaymentOptionsMethodToGetDBRecords();

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@{    
List<PaymentOption> myPaymentOptionList = ViewBag.PaymentOptionGridSource;

WebGrid paymentOptionWebGrid = new WebGrid(
    null,
    canPage: true,
    defaultSort: "ID"
    );
paymentOptionWebGrid.Bind(
    myPaymentOptionList,
    autoSortAndPage: true
    );
}

@paymentOptionWebGrid.GetHtml (
tableStyle: "table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive",

columns: paymentOptionWebGrid.Columns(
    paymentOptionWebGrid.Column("PaymentOptionDescription", "Payment Method", style: "span1", canSort: false),
    paymentOptionWebGrid.Column("MyPaymentOptionModelPropertyHere", "My Column Header Here", style: "span2", canSort: false),

    /* Same logic for all other columns as above */

    )
```

Comment: Thanks. I do have the descriptions in a different table. How would I do the mapping if the data binding is done on page load.